# Access to tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

1.Create a blank new `View Controller` in `Storyboard`. Bind it to custom class `ViewController`.

2.Drag a `Table View` into `View Controller`.

3.Inherit `UITableViewDataSource` in `ViewController`'s code.

Now I use function `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` in `ViewController`, but it can not be labelled `override`,obviously the function does not work, therefore this tableView shows blank only.

I have set both view and custom class for table view cell properly, which I think is irrelevant here.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must inherit UITableViewDelegate, drag the Tableview in your Storyboard in your code, and in viewDidLoad method, you add these lines:

```
tableView.datasource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

Also, cellForRowAtIndexPath may not be called because one(or more) of the following reasons:

**numberOfRowsInSection returns 0**

**numberOfSectionsInTableView return 0**

**dataSource not properly set**

**heightForRowAtIndexPath returns 0**

**table has frame size of 0 for height and/or width**